# Match and entire field

Tags: elasticsearch

For the query: `'goodbye cruel world'` and a field called 'title'.
Let's say I have the documents:

```
1. {'title': 'goodbye cruel'}   
2. {'title': 'goodbye world'}   
3. {'title': 'cruel world'}   
4. {'title': 'goodbye cruel world'}   
5. {'title': 'goodbye very cruel world'}
```

I want a query to match only documents 4 and 5 because they have all the terms in the query. I can't figure any way to accomplish this.
I thought about keeping the length of the field indexed but it would require querying every word combinations, what else can I do?

---

**I just figured I asked the wrong question :(**
I marked the answer as correct but what I really wanted to ask is:

For the query: `'goodbye cruel world'` and a field called 'title'.
Let's say I have the documents:

```
1. {'title': 'goodbye cruel'}   
2. {'title': 'goodbye world'}   
3. {'title': 'cruel world'}   
4. {'title': 'goodbye cruel world'}   
5. {'title': 'goodbye very cruel world'}
5. {'title': 'hello cruel world'}
```

I want a query to match documents 1, 2, 3, 4 but not 5 or 6, because they don't have all the terms in the query.

(I asked a similar looking question before and it was answered correctly, but it was not what I actually  wanted to asked so I'm submitting this as a different question)

Comment: how are you choosing 4 and 5? what makes them 'special'/unique?

Comment: Oh right, I forgot. The have all the terms in the query!

Comment: something like: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html??

Comment: It's not the same. Here I'm matching only on a single field. I just want to match all the words in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `match_phrase` query with a `slop` of 1.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": {
        "query": "goodbye cruel world",
        "slop": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more info:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html

Comment: You're right, but sadly I now understand that I asked the wrong question :(